# After updating library in Android Studio, cannot see any class

Tags: android, android-studio

I have this in my build.gradle file, in the dependencies section:

```
compile 'com.google.android.exoplayer:exoplayer:r1.4.2'
```

I need to update to this:

```
compile 'com.google.android.exoplayer:exoplayer:r1.5.0'
```

When I do this in my current project, Android Studio can no longer see any of the classes that exoplayer has to offer. As a result, I cannot import or use anything.

If, however, I start a new project and add the correct line in the dependencies section, it works perfectly.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Have you synchronized your project after changing your build.gradle?

Comment: yes, it's synchronized

Comment: see gradle console log

Comment: the gradle log is empty after changing to 1.5.0 and synchronizing...is this right?

Comment: I have this exact same problem - updating exoplayer to 1.5.0 (or any version above that). Did you ever solve it?

Comment: I also reported this as an isse to ExoPlayer: https://github.com/google/ExoPlayer/issues/987

Comment: Haven't solved it! I kept the version at 1.4.2 and I think that when I have the time I will download the library and add it like that

Comment: I think I have solved it - I just bit the bullet and fixed every compiler error without help from AS (look up changed method signatures in the source code, etc.) (You do get compiler errors if you "build project", don't you? If not, try gradle from the command line). And as soon as I fixed the last one, all the imports started working again and now also keep working if I introduce one again... very weird...